# Best cheap GUI for converting to f4v

Tags: user-interface, ffmpeg, converters

I need to give one client the ability to convert some videos to f4v h264 before loading it up to an AIR app.

I normally doing with the Adobe Media Encoder CS4 but that only ships with adobe products (you can't download it as a free standalone app - which, *start rant* is odd, you'd think they would push the format - Microsoft's competing expresssion encoder is free *end rant*)

Anyway, I need to get a (hopefully not too expensive, but willing to pay for it) good 3rd part app that can take any video and convert it to an f4v.

Can you suggest any? Everything i've found is horrible or jammed with ads and crap.

What would you use? Any suggestion?

(please don't just say ffmpeg - I know it can do it but we need to good simple GUI)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just create a simple front-end for ffmpeg? I can't imagine it'd take long to whip something up in WinForms or whatever.

Comment: Sure, but I'd rather not re-invent the wheel. It'd also likely be cheaper to buy than spending dev time on it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked http://handbrake.fr/

Comment: Hey, woaa, old question. Forgot I asked it :) Yeah, handbrake definitely fits the bill, there's even a good tut for http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html.
Credit given to you for taking time to answer :)